# Proper handling in PostgreSQL/PostGIS only after many queries?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, query, route

I am trying to analyze GPS data of a parade on a fixed route with a certain variance due to the urban surrounding (canyoning). I'd like to project the GPS waypoints to the nearest points on the route underlying linestrings.
I add a new column in the same table in which the data is located and update this with the calculated data. But during the first few queries I get for all projected waypoints the projection of the first point.
Only if I repeat the query a few times the desired output is generated.
Because I'm a beginner in programming I can not figure out what seems to be the trouble.

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('vehicle_2015_02','projected_point',4326,'POINT',2, false);
UPDATE vehicle_2015_02 v02
SET projected_point = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
    romo2015_way.st_makeline,
    ST_LineLocatePoint(
        romo2015_way.st_makeline,
        vehicle_2015_02.geom
    ))
FROM romo2015_way, vehicle_2015_02;
```

- vehicle_2015_02:      table with GPS waypoints+timestamp as points
- projected_point:      new column in table "vehicle_2015_02" as points
- romo2015_way:         table with route as points

Comment: Is it possible that the first few runs through it, either function returns NULL values? Have you tried changing your UPDATE to a SELECT and reviewing what is returned for both your ST_LineInterpolatePoint and ST_LineLocatePoint functions? You might also want to limit your values based on some sort of proximity; taking the Cartesian Product of both romo2015_way and vehicle_2015_02 will end up comparing every point with every linestring for each point in vehicle_2015_02. That 2nd mention of vehicle_2015_02 (in UPDATE ... FROM) might be a problem.

Comment: I tried this now. The peculiar thing is that when I review what is returned by these functions using only SELECT I get proper results. I agree with you that it is more convenient to limit the values in the calculation. And I agree with you that the 2nd mention of the vehicle_2015_02 table makes the trouble. I changed the code as follows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this actually works now, maybe someone could explain it, but after many tries I succeded by using the following code:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('vehicle_2015_02','projected_point',4326,'POINT',2, false);
UPDATE vehicle_2015_02 v02
SET projected_point = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(romo2015_way.st_makeline,
    ST_LineLocatePoint(romo2015_way.st_makeline,vehicle_2015_02.geom))
FROM romo2015_way, (SELECT * FROM vehicle_2015_02) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rewrite your UPDATE statement, using an explicit join.

```
UPDATE vehicle_2015_02 v02
SET projected_point = q.newpoint
FROM (
   SELECT vehicle_2015_02.objectid, 
          ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
              romo2015_way.st_makeline,
              ST_LineLocatePoint(
                 romo2015_way.st_makeline,
                 vehicle_2015_02.geom
           )) as newpoint
   from romo2015_way, vehicle_2015_02
) q 
where q.objectid = v02.objectid;
```

Apologies if this isn't 100% correct. Once you get this query working, it might be worthwhile using EXPLAIN on both, so you can see how the database handles the two queries differently.